# How to add a lead to a specific campaign via API

Tags: api, leads, campaign

I'm using node-salesforce to create leads when they submit a form. I need that lead to also be part of a campaign, here is my code:

```
conn.sobject("Lead").create({
   email : req.body.signUpEmail,
   firstname : req.body.first_name,
   lastname : req.body.last_name,
   title : req.body.job_title,
   company : req.body.company,
   leadsource: 'Clearing Microsite'
}, function(err, ret) {
   if (err || !ret.success) { 
       return console.error(err, ret); 
}
```

I've tried just putting campaign_id in the json object but no luck, any ideas? I have the campaign_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a campaignMember record to link the Lead and the Campaign together after creating the Lead. That record is auto-created when creating a Lead (and filling the Campaign field) via the GUI but it's not available via the API.

There's a SFDC help article on this as well:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004171&language=en_US

Comment: so after I create the lead i'll have to create another sobject using the newly created lead's id like so:

`conn.sobject("campaignMember").create({lead_id: *leadsID*, campaign_id: campaign_id})`

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: If this works I am going to be so happy man! Thank you for your help, never would have guessed that, will reply if it works.

Comment: You legend, worked like a charm! Thank you man, would upvote so hard if i had the reputation.

Comment: @guy I came across the same situation for SalesForce SOAP API in C# application. But I could not find any good example to start with. Do you have any code snippet to illustrate this?

Comment: CampaignMember is an object like any other, so inserting it will work the same way as for other objects. Here's the general documentation on which fields it has: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm and here's some example code on updating (similar code can be used for inserting): http://www.rubencanton.com/blog/2012/02/updating-campaign-member-using-salesforce-api-and-c.html If you need more help I'd advice to post a new question so others can help you as well.