# How to assign or create a Lead in Campaign using SOAP API in C#

Tags: leads, campaign, campaign-member

I came across a situation where I am searching for `Phone Number`. If this `Phone Number` is found in `Campaign`, then I want to create a `Lead` and assign this `Lead` to the `Campaign` that contains the `Phone Number`.

I am really newbie to `SalesForce` and don't know how to accomplish this.
I referred the following post also but I could not understand how can I resemble the same in my scenario.
[How to add a lead to a specific campaign via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55414/how-to-add-a-lead-to-a-specific-campaign-via-api)

I just know that in order to create a `Lead` and assign it to `Campaign`, we have to use `CampaignMember` class. But I don't know how this actually works.

If anybody has come across this situation, then a sample code/snippet would let me in the right direction to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for those who might have come across like me but were unable to dig into this.

```
public void CreateAndAssignLeadToCampaign(SforceService binding)
        {
            // Create a new Lead and assign various properties
            Lead lead = new Lead();

            lead.FirstName = "John";
            lead.LastName = "Brown";
            lead.Company = "ABC Corporation";
            lead.LeadSource = "Advertisement";

            QueryResult qr = binding.query("Select Id from Campaign where Name = " +
                "'My Campaign'");
            Campaign campaign = (Campaign)qr.records[0];
            SaveResult[] sr = binding.create(new sObject[] { lead });
            foreach (SaveResult s in sr)
            {
                if (s.success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully created Lead with ID: {0}", s.id);
                    CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();
                    cm.CampaignId = campaign.Id;
                    cm.LeadId = sr[0].id;
                    SaveResult[] sr2 = binding.create(new sObject[]{cm});
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error creating Lead: {0}", s.errors[0].message);
                }
            }
}
```

But still I want to improve this. Because this will always create a Lead and then assign it to the Campaign. But I want to use `upsert()` method in place of `create()` method. 
May be someone can still improve this.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at this [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/) which is especially for SOAP API and Salesforce. There you have all the references to all the objects and how to get started.

Also why do you need to integrate with SOAP? Can you use REST ?

Comment: SOAP API is much more powerful than REST, as I personally believe because it gives you necessary classes and methods through which you can directly interact with your SalesForce database.

Comment: That's fine, the documentation will help you. I've created and use a C# library to interact with Salesforce using REST using async capabilities and it`s very flexible and there are tons of examples out there and was curious of SOAP. See the GitHub resource https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET. I even developed a fluent interface so the test analysts will use and not even need to know the various method Salesforce has.

Comment: That's really awesome! I will definitely give a try to this and will let you know. Thanks for your support dude!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. I was in the same situation as you 6 months ago and if I can save you 10-15 hours then I`m happy. Have fun coding!